# Solving Screenlock Bypass Issue for Expired User Account

Tags: shell-script, security, users, xubuntu

I have created a script that I deploy to my children's computers via Salt.  The script implements allowed working hours and has worked well, but one of my children have found a way of bypassing this and I can't work out how to fix this.

I have used timekpr, but was looking for something I could centrally control.  I also found that timekpr prevented their running tasks from continuing while locked.

The children's computers are running Xubuntu 15.04, fully patched with passwordless login (there is a password, but they don't need to know it)

If they lock the screen manually by clicking the padlock in the program menu before the script locks their session, they can unlock their session even while their user account is in an expired state.  They can only do this once before expected behaviour returns.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

users[0]='child1'
users[1]='child2'
users[2]='child3'

lock[0]=1930
lock[1]=1930
lock[2]=1930

unlock[0]=1300
unlock[1]=1300
unlock[2]=1300

# clean up at AT jobs that may already exist
for i in `atq | cut -f1`;
do
    if at -c $i | grep -q '^/root/userRestrictions.sh$'
    then
        atrm $i
    fi
done

currTime=`date +%k%M`

for i in {0..2}
do
    if id -u "${users[i]}" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # username exists
        if [ "$currTime" -ge ${unlock[i]} ] && [ "$currTime" -lt ${lock[i]} ]; then 
            # current time is between unlock and lock time

            # unlock the users account
            /usr/bin/chage -E -1 ${users[i]}

            # run this script again at the lock time
            atHour=$(( ${lock[i]} / 100 ))
            # extract minutes and pad with zeros
            atMinute=$(( ${lock[i]} % 100 ))
            atMinute=`printf %02d $atMinute`
            echo "/root/userRestrictions.sh" | at "$atHour:$atMinute"

        else
            # current time is after lock time or before unlock time

            # lock the users account
            /usr/bin/chage -E 0 ${users[i]}

            # lock screen if the user is logged in at all
            if w | cut -d " " -f1 | grep -Fxq "${users[i]}"
            then
                XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0 dm-tool lock
            fi

            # run this script again at the unlock time
            atHour=$(( ${unlock[i]} / 100 ))
            # extract minutes and pad with zeros
            atMinute=$(( ${unlock[i]} % 100))
            atMinute=`printf %02d $atMinute`
            echo "/root/userRestrictions.sh" | at "$atHour:$atMinute"
        fi
    fi
done
```